# Aptana problems - not show/read interrogation point "?" / encoding issues

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, ide, aptana3, conditional-operator

I just downloaded Aptana 3 built 3.61.201410201044 and i'm experiencing an issue:

- Everytime i try to type the question mark "?" aptana enable/ disable "Show whitespace characters" option

I tried using both <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> and it didn't work
Even if i copy/paste a text that use the character, it doesn't work on my method when running.

I'm on Windows 7; my keyboard is PT-Br and all the encodings (default and each file) are set to UTF-8

I don't know what to do, as i need this symbol to use many methods in Ruby...

I googled this issue for a long time before asking here, and just read about setting the encoding to utf-8 but i did it and didn't work.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after many tries i found how to solve it. I'll post here just in case somebody else need:

Go to 
Preferences> General> Keys
then search for "Show whitespace characters" and delet the binding (keys shortcut / hotkeys)